# What could this python process be?

Tags: security, python

I noticed some strange python process trying to access IPs which seem to belong to Google, such as `74.125.77.109` (according to whois). The process has this initialization command in `ps`:

```
bash -c P=python2; $P -V 2>/dev/null || P=python; "$P" -c 'import sys; \
  skip_imports=1; verbosity=2; exec compile(sys.stdin.read(764), \
  "assembler.py", "exec")'
```

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Does not look good from the security POV. Please do #locate assembler.py and try to open that file.

Comment: Try running `pstree -H the_pid_of_that_procees`. It could give you better clues as to what exactly spawned that.

Comment: I have seen Google using python for internal components before, but this is a bit odd. All of the tips here are good: find assembler.py, check out the process tree, and take a look in the proc filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it belongs to [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) which was running at that time.

Answer (score 2):

`ls -l /proc/<pid>` and `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` may tell you more.